# Re-arrange and aggregate R Rows

Tags: r, dataframe, tidyr

edit --- i have cleaned up the question to be smaller in scope.

I am trying to aggregate a dataframe in the following form, but have become stuck.

This is an isdn log output from a telephone system, so it contains calls occurring at the same time all throughout the log. These calls are of an incoming nature rather than outgoing.

The dataframe looks like below:

```
"V1" "V2""V3""V4"   "V5"        "V6"        "V7"                   "V8"
"1" "Oct" "" "2" "00:00:01" "10.20.5.31" "82189056:" "Oct  2 00:00:01.326 AEDST: ISDN Se0/0/0:15 Q931: RX <- SETUP pd = 8  callref = 0x174E "
"2" "Oct" "" "2" "00:00:01" "10.20.5.31" "82189057:" "  Bearer Capability i = 0x8090A3 "
"3" "Oct" "" "2" "00:00:01" "10.20.5.31" "82189058:" "      Standard = CCITT "
"4" "Oct" "" "2" "00:00:01" "10.20.5.31" "82189059:" "      Transfer Capability = Speech  "
"5" "Oct" "" "2" "00:00:01" "10.20.5.31" "82189060:" "      Transfer Mode = Circuit "
"6" "Oct" "" "2" "00:00:01" "10.20.5.31" "82189061:" "      Transfer Rate = 64 kbit/s "
"7" "Oct" "" "2" "00:00:01" "10.20.5.31" "82189062:" "  Channel ID i = 0xA1839B "
"8" "Oct" "" "2" "00:00:01" "10.20.5.31" "82189063:" "      Preferred, Channel 27 "
"9" "Oct" "" "2" "00:00:01" "10.20.5.31" "82189064:" "  Calling Party Number i = 0x2183, '00123456789' "
"10" "Oct" "" "2" "00:00:01" "10.20.5.31" "82189065:" "     Plan:ISDN, Type:National "
"11" "Oct" "" "2" "00:00:01" "10.20.5.31" "82189066:" " Called Party Number i = 0xC1, '0123456' "
"12" "Oct" "" "2" "00:00:01" "10.20.5.31" "82189067:" "     Plan:ISDN, Type:Subscriber(local) "
"13" "Oct" "" "2" "00:00:01" "10.20.5.31" "82189068:" " Sending Complete"
"14" "Oct" "" "2" "00:00:01" "10.20.5.31" "82189069:" "Oct  2 00:00:01.334 AEDST: ISDN Se0/0/0:15 Q931: TX -> CALL_PROC pd = 8  callref = 0x974E "
"15" "Oct" "" "2" "00:00:01" "10.20.5.31" "82189070:" " Channel ID i = 0xA9839B "
"16" "Oct" "" "2" "00:00:01" "10.20.5.31" "82189071:" "     Exclusive, Channel 27"
"17" "Oct" "" "2" "00:00:02" "10.20.5.31" "82189072:" "Oct  2 00:00:01.350 AEDST: ISDN Se0/0/0:15 Q931: TX -> ALERTING pd = 8  callref = 0x974E "
"18" "Oct" "" "2" "00:00:02" "10.20.5.31" "82189073:" " Progress Ind i = 0x8088 - In-band info or appropriate now available "
"19" "Oct" "" "2" "00:00:02" "10.20.5.31" "82189074:" "Oct  2 00:00:01.358 AEDST: ISDN Se0/0/0:15 Q931: TX -> CONNECT pd = 8  callref = 0x974E"
"20" "Oct" "" "2" "00:00:02" "10.20.5.31" "82189075:" "Oct  2 00:00:01.382 AEDST: ISDN Se0/0/0:15 Q931: RX <- CONNECT_ACK pd = 8  callref = 0x174E"
"21" "Oct" "" "2" "00:00:19" "10.20.5.30" "81488302:" "Oct  2 00:00:18.210 AEDST: ISDN Se0/0/0:15 Q931: TX -> DISCONNECT pd = 8  callref = 0x9AC7 "
"22" "Oct" "" "2" "00:00:19" "10.20.5.30" "81488303:" " Cause i = 0x8090 - Normal call clearing"
"23" "Oct" "" "2" "00:00:19" "10.20.5.30" "81488304:" "Oct  2 00:00:18.290 AEDST: ISDN Se0/0/0:15 Q931: RX <- RELEASE pd = 8  callref = 0x1AC7"
"24" "Oct" "" "2" "00:00:19" "10.20.5.30" "81488305:" "Oct  2 00:00:18.314 AEDST: ISDN Se0/0/0:15 Q931: TX -> RELEASE_COMP pd = 8  callref = 0x9AC7"
"25" "Oct" "" "2" "00:00:21" "10.20.5.31" "82189076:" "Oct  2 00:00:21.053 AEDST: ISDN Se0/1/0:15 Q931: RX <- SETUP pd = 8  callref = 0x093A "
```

I would like the dataset to look like below:

```
    "V1" "V2""V3""V4"   "V5"        "V6"        "V7"    "UniqueId"       "V8"
    "1" "Oct" "" "2" "00:00:01" "10.20.5.31" "82189056:" "0x174E" "Oct  2 00:00:01.326 AEDST: ISDN Se0/0/0:15 Q931: RX <- SETUP pd = 8  callref = 0x174E "
    "2" "Oct" "" "2" "00:00:01" "10.20.5.31" "82189057:" "0x174E" " Bearer Capability i = 0x8090A3 "
    "3" "Oct" "" "2" "00:00:01" "10.20.5.31" "82189058:" "0x174E" "      Standard = CCITT "
   ....
    "21" "Oct" "" "2" "00:00:19" "10.20.5.30" "81488302:" "0x9AC7" "Oct  2 00:00:18.210 AEDST: ISDN Se0/0/0:15 Q931: TX -> DISCONNECT pd = 8  callref = 0x9AC7 "
```

To re-iterate:

- Call reference is the unique way to identify this dataset, also known
  as callref for example 0x174E (this is the only way to find unique calls
  within the dataset). 
  This is the new column (UniqueId) in the requested dataframe.
- Any rows below also will have the same callref id pasted in the new column until it hits another line which states either the same callref or another call ref.
- Bonus points for anyone who can collapse these lines into one line, every time a callref is shown. Note that this can happen in a few different states (when the line that contains callref also contains TX -> CALL_PROC, TX -> ALERTING, TX -> CONNECT, RX <- CONNECT_ACK and a few others.)

For example, I have combined the V7 column of rows 1,2 and 3 as they belong to the same callref

```
    "V1" "V2""V3""V4"   "V5"        "V6"        "V7"    "UniqueId"       "V8"
    "1" "Oct" "" "2" "00:00:01" "10.20.5.31" "82189056:" "0x174E" "Oct  2 00:00:01.326 AEDST: ISDN Se0/0/0:15 Q931: RX <- SETUP pd = 8  callref = 0x174E \n Bearer Capability i = 0x8090A3 \n Standard = CCITT"
```

Any answers are appreciated.

Comment: Can you make it a reproducible example so I can play with it in R? I’m having a hard time understanding how your dataset is laid out. Please check out documentation for reproducible examples.

Comment: I have now changed the original table with an example that can be copied into a text file and then imported into r using a read.table(). This might not be elegant, but this is what I know how to do. Please let me know if this change helped in any way.

Comment: Please edit the question with the output of `dput(log_entry)` instead of that text format, like this we will have an **exact copy** of your data.

Comment: also I'm a bit confused with how you want the data to look at the end. Your output example looks exactly like the input.

Comment: cleaned up the question a bit more. i have done a str_split_fixed to make more columns up and flesh the dataframe out a bit more.

Comment: I have found the following reg exp to work to find the unique id for a call - (?<=callref = ).*?(?=\s)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this is a bit messy of an answer but I did my best.

You can probably skip my `read.fwf` because you did the same with `str_split`. I was just trying to get the data in a workable format.

I first read in the info, separating out some of the columns

```
example1 <- read.fwf("ex.csv", widths = c(1, 6, 10, 10, 10, 1000), strip.white = T)
```

Turned everything into character strings instead of factors, removed the first row headers, and the renamed the columns.

```
example <- example1 %>%
  mutate_all(.funs = as.character) %>%
  slice(-1) %>%
  select(-1,
         Date = 2,
         Time = 3,
         IP = 4,
         id = 5,
         Description = 6)
```

I then indexed the first spots where callref occurs, and then grouped by those blocks of text.

```
x <- which(grepl("callref", example$Description))

example <- example %>%
  mutate(callref = ifelse(grepl("callref", Description), 1, 0),
         group = rep(x, c(diff(c(x, x))[1:length(x)-1], nrow(.) - x[length(x)]+1)))
```

after the `example` df is grouped, I summarise the text, to past the descriptions within the group. I think this was the main thing you were looking to do?

```
example2 <- example %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  summarise(text = paste(Description, collapse = "*"))
```

After that I join it back to the main `example` df, and I use separate to separate out some of the important information. We can grab the RX_TX this way, as well as the callref id. If you want, you can split out any other important information and then I would recommend using the `spread` function from tidyr to turn that information into columns so you can further clean it up for analysis.

```
example3 <- example %>%
  filter(callref == 1) %>%
  left_join(example2, by = "group") %>%
  select(-Description) %>%
  rename(Description = text) %>%
  separate(Description, into = c("firstpart", "RX_TX"), sep = "Q931: ") %>%
  separate(RX_TX, into = c("RX_TX", "Info"), sep = "pd = 8") %>%
  mutate(Call_Ref = substr(gsub("callref \\= ", "", Info), 1, 8))
```

Comment: This is exactly what I have been looking for! I will be re-using this code for many scenarios that I face with my datasets. Thank You!

Comment: I'm glad it works for you! This was an interesting one to do. :)

Comment: I was hoping to ask for some tips on how I can training to get to the level of how you have been able to resolve this question. I figured out the pseudo code but I could not put it all together with summarise, rep and group. What type of training, resources, courses would you recommend? Any tips would be highly appreciated.

Comment: I used data camp to teach myself R, alongside working on work projects and stack overflow. Probably 40% datacamp, and 60% stack overflow tbh. Having projects to work on teaches me new skills. This problem for example I had to google a number of things. The summarise pasting the text together isn't something I've ever normally done, since I don't work with text very often. Usually use summarise with numbers. And finding out the diff was also googling on stack overflow and playing around with it. Everything else was `dplyr` which I've used extensively. I think it is just new projects and time!